# Какой extention выбрать для работы с MySQL в PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Насколько я знаю, существует `mysql`, `mysqli` и пр... Раньше я использовал `mysql`, но это было лет 5 назад. Сейчас ситуация существенно поменялась, и многие статьи рекомендуют использовать `mysqli`.

Уважаемые знатоки PHP программирования, помогите опытом, чем же так хорош `mysqli` или может стоит использовать что-то другое?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Расширение `mysql` официально признано устаревшим. Это означает, что нет гарантий его дальнейшей поддержки (в том числе и с точки зрения безопасности). Поэтому это расширение *нельзя* использовать ни в одном новом проекте.

Остается выбор между `mysqli` и `PDO`.

**Расширение `mysqli`**

`mysqli` - это наиболее простая замена `mysql`. Большинство функций и методов `mysqli` имеют синтаксис, схожий с синтаксисом расширения `mysql`. Это позволяет достаточно просто переключится с одного расширения на другое. Например:

```
// mysql
$link = mysql_connect();
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tbl', $link);
var_dump(mysql_fetch_assoc($res));


// mysqli
$link = mysqli_connect();
$res = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM tbl');
var_dump(mysqli_fetch_assoc($res));
```

В тоже время, есть и ряд улучшений, связанных безопасностью (плейсхолдеры) и объектным подходом. Очевидный минус `mysqli` - привязка кода к работе с MySQL. В ряде случаев, это может затруднить переход к использованию других баз данных (если это конечно потребуется).

**Расширение `PDO`**

`PDO` представляет собой дополнительный уровень абстракции над базой данных. Теоретически, один и тот же PHP код может работать с любой SQL совместимой базой данных, если для нее есть соответствующий драйвер PDO. (На практике, проблема с различными БД все равно остается из за различий в синтаксисе SQL.) `PDO` проповедует объектный подход, поэтому и код будет существенно отличаться от кода с использованием `mysql`. Например:

```
// mysql
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('testdb', $link);
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tbl', $link);
var_dump(mysql_fetch_assoc($res));

// PDO
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'user', 'pass');
$stm = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl');
$stm->execute();
var_dump($stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Помимо прочего, `PDO` предоставляет набор дополнительных возможностей, связанных с безопастностью (плейсхолдеры) и скоростью выполнения запроса (подготовленные запросы). Хотя этих возможностей нет `mysql`, часть из них реализована в `mysqli`.

**Резюмирую**: в большинстве случаев, я бы рекомендовал использовать `PDO`, поскольку интерфейс работы с `mysqli` слишком низкоуровневый и часто требует создания собственного уровня абстракции над БД.

Comment: Вы хотя бы комментируйте, за что минусуете :)

Comment: Я не минусовал... Приведите пример использования PDO, как привели разницу mysql и mysqli. Интересно посмотреть.

Comment: @GrayHoax, добавил пример кода с использованием `PDO`

Answer (score 2):

Выбор очень прост.

Если ты понимаешь необходимость использования дополнительного уровня абстракции над низкоуровневыми функциями доступа к БД, и в состоянии написать такой, то надо использовать mysqli.

В противном случае единственно правильным выбором будет PDO.

В любом случае, главой ошибкой будет, если сменив экстеншен ты сохранишь старый подход, добавляя переменные в запрос напрямую. Единственная причина, по которой надо переходить на новые экстеншены - это использование подготовленных выражений. Иначе смысла переходить нет - гуано-кодить можно продолжать и на старом экстеншене.

В свете вышесказанного не надо обманываться видимой легкостью перехода на mysqli. Работа с подготовленными выражениями никакого аналога в  mysql не имеет, и, следовательно, никакой "простоты" при переходе не предоставляет.

Comment: Вы  не правы, говоря что "_Единственная причина, по которой надо переходить на новые экстеншены - это использование подготовленных выражений_". Есть и другая причина -- надежность кода. Вот откажется завтра сообщество PHP фиксить дыры в `mysql` и что тогда? В авральном режиме переходить на `mysqli`?

Comment: Вы видимо забыли, что в `mysqli` есть `mysqli_query`, которую можно использовать аналогично `mysql_query`: `$res = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT ...'); mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);`. Вполне работает _без подготовленных выражений_. Хотя этот путь и не является идеологически верным, зато с помощью него можно преобразовать код `mysql` в `mysqli` с минимальными трудозатратами.

Answer (score -4):

Если у тебя весь проект реализован на классах я бы рекомендовал смотреть в сторону Doctrine 2 если нет тогда PDO.

Есть мнение что mysqli это низкоуровневой расширения, которое должно использоваться для написания  библиотек.

Comment: "Классовость" проекта вовсе не подразумевает использования в нем ORM.

Comment: Согласен. Но вопрос не об этом а существующих расширений для работы с БД. Есть расширение Doctrine о котором выше не кто не написал. Если автору понадобится ответы на вопросы в каких случаях какое лучше выбрать расширение, я полагаю он создаст отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Вы поосторожнее с выражениями. Во-первых Doctrine - это не расширение PHP (как mysql, mysqli, PDO) а отдельная библиотека. Во-вторых, Doctrine (если вы имеете в виду Doctrine DBAL) построена поверх PDO. Если же речь о Doctrine ORM, то она построена поверх Doctrine DBAL.

Comment: Да и потом, автор уже задал вопрос какое именно **расширение** (не библиотеку) лучше выбрать.