# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php

1) `php7` распакован в папку `c:\apps\php7`. Не могу запустить следующий скрипт:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "qwe", "qwe");
?>
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

Как я понял проблема в том, что не загружено расширение для mysql. Но чтобы его загрузить нужно раскомментировать соответствующую строку в файле `php.ini`. Но найти такой файл я никак не смог.

2) Попробовал сделать следующее.

```
<?php
dl('php_mysqli.dll');
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
?>
```

Но снова получил ошибку:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\php_mysqli.dll'
```

Видимо `php` ищет расширение не там где надо.

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: 1000 лет не работал с чистым mysql, но помнится что в mysqli функция mysqli_connect, а не mysql_connect. для mysql_connect должно быть другое расширение

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php: Warning
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension

Comment: На всякий случай сообщаю: расширение mysqli содержит функции, чьи имена начинаются с `mysqli_` =)

Comment: Поменял на mysqli_connect. Ошибка все равно осталась. `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\php_mysqli.dll'`

Comment: А сам файл там есть?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Я ведь описал в вопросе что где расположено.

Answer (score 4):

Расширение `mysql` было признано устаревшим начиная с PHP 5.5.0 и полностью удалено в версии PHP 7. Похоже вам пора переходить на более современные средства работы с базой:

- [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) - более современный вариант вендор-специфического коннектора к MySQL. Функциональный интерфейс этой библиотеки, позволяет несколько сгладить переход с `mysql` на `mysqli`. Большинство функций `mysqli` имеют сигнатуры, похожие на функции `mysql` (например, [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) и [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php)). Тем не менее, я **настоятельно рекомендую** использовать объектный интерфейс этой библиотеки.
- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) - библиотека, представляющая собой полноценный ООП инструментарий для работы с БД. Интерфейс этой библиотеки позволяет абстрагироваться от того, с какой именно базой происходит работы. (Хотя различия в синтаксисе SQL все равно останутся.)

В качестве дополнения приведу [ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/448720/182771) на другой вопрос, посвященный сравнению PDO и mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, правильно ли указан путь к `extension_dir` в `php.ini`.

В этой директории должна лежать `php_mysqli.dll`.
Обычно это `ext` папка в корне `php`.