# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> mysql_connect() in
> C:\Users\user\Desktop\open\OpenServer\domains\lazar.ua\index.php:11
> Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
> C:\Users\user\Desktop\open\OpenServer\domains\lazar.ua\index.php on
> line 11

```
    <?php
    //Отключаем лимит ожидания и объявляем переменные
set_time_limit(0);
$content=NULL;$num_pages=NULL;
//Подключение к базе
//Подключаемся к базе данных
define ("HOST", "lazar.ua");
define ("DATABASE", "test");
define ("MYSQL_USER", "roor");
define ("MYSQL_PASS", "root");
mysql_connect(HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS);mysql_query("set names utf8");mysql_select_db(DATABASE);
//Узнаём кол-во страниц
$content=file_get_contents('http://bash.im/');
preg_match('|max="(.*?)"|is',$content,$num_pages);
//Парсим каждую страницу
for ($i=1; $i <= $num_pages[1]; $i++){$i2=false;
    //Грузим страницы, вырезаем цитаты
    $content=file_get_contents('http://bash.im/index/'.$i);
    $quotes=explode('<span class="date">',$content);
    foreach($quotes as $quote){
        if($i2==false){$i2=true;continue;}
        //Номер цитаты
        preg_match('|class="id">#(.*?)</a>|is',$quote,$quote_id);
        //Текст цитаты
        preg_match('|<div class="text">(.*?)</div>|is',$quote,$quote_text);
        //Конвертация текста в UTF-8 и экранирование символов
        $quote_text=strip_tags(addslashes(htmlspecialchars(trim(iconv("windows-1251","UTF-8",$quote_text[1])))));
        //Вписываем в базу
        if($quote_text!=NULL){mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bash`(`id`,`quote_id`,`quote_text`) VALUES (NULL,'{$quote_id[1]}','{$quote_text}')");}
            }
    //От перезагрузки
    sleep(2);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql\_connect()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522542/uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect)

Comment: `mysql_` умер дцать лет назад. Хватит уже заниматься некрофилией)

Comment: мне нужна помощь по нему

Comment: Прочтите сообщение в красной плашке в [mysql_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

Answer (score 1):

Функции `mysql_*` (всё, что начинается с `mysql_`) не поддерживаются, начиная с PHP 7.

### Что делать?

Есть как минимум две альтернативы:

- [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php). современно, нормальное ООП, всё при нём. Есть свои недостатки, но у кого их нет? В любом случае, рекомендовано лучшими слониководами (теми, кто не использует ORM и прочие обёртки над PDO).
- [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php). В целом тоже ничего, но PDO лучше хотя бы потому, что умеет поддерживать несколько различных СУБД и лучше работает с подготовленными запросами. Однако если вам надо быстро что-то перевести со старого `mysql_*`-кода, возможно, MySQLi вам понравится больше.